# In Legal English (law) is there an authoritative meaning to “over the age of ‘X’”?

Tags: ambiguity, legalese

[This is a question about Legal English, that is, English language used in legal writing, not about strict usage of English outside of legal writing. —DN]

In Legal English what does “over the age of ‘X’” mean? I see both these wordings in California Law:

1. “over the age of 18”
2. “age 18 or older”

Literally interpreted, these have different meanings. I would tend to prefer the second wording, but is there some reference that defines and clarifies the correct, authoritative or preferred wording in law?

Comment: Voting to close as too localized.  The literal meaning is clear (I think) and any legal implications would be something only a lawyer could answer.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic. At best this would be a point of law not language, but in practice lawyers would probably be needed to debate the point for each specific law that included such a vague phrase as “over the age of 18”.

Comment: If not here, where should this question about English language and usage be posted?

Answer (score 1):

It has its ordinary English meaning of “having lived for eighteen years”. It will, consequently, be legally construed as having reached one’s eighteenth birthday.

A phrase only has a separate, legal, meaning when it is a [term of art](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Term+of+Art) or when a particular statute supplies one. In those cases, the legal meaning would take precedence over the ordinary English meaning. However, “over the age of” is not a term of art: it does not appear in law dictionaries. Nor am I aware of it being defined by a definition section of any California statute.

The legal doctrine which says that a word is to be construed using its ordinary English meaning in the absence of a term of art or a definition in the statute is the “plain meaning rule”. For an introduction to the various rules of interpretation of legal English, start with the *Wikipedia* article “[Statutory interpretation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statutory_interpretation)”.

Comment: Downvoted, as you seem to have given your personal opinion. I asked for authoritative references.

Comment: I have elaborated.

Comment: @danorton: Question downvoted (see [IMNAL](http://www.acronymfinder.com/I'm-Not-a-Lawyer-(IMNAL).html)). There certainly won't be an internationally-recognised standard, for law or any other purpose, as to exactly what *“over the age of 18”* means. To be honest, I would be gobsmacked if even the judiciary within one single country had such a definition.

Comment: +1 so MetaEd can get some recompense for his efforts before the question gets closed!

Comment: Removed downvote for authoritative reference.